# Can a 302 redirect cross the same origin policy?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

The parent window url is `a.com/a`, the inner iframe url is `b.com`. But when iframe requests b.com, there is a 302 to `a.com/b`.

In `a.com/b` there is a script: `window.parent.document`.

Will the script be blocked by the same origin policy?